# Удаление tr если в одном из td не найдено определенное слово

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть таблица такого типа

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="uTable user-list">
<tbody>
    <tr><th class="uTopTd">Телефон</th><th class="uTopTd">Группа</th><th class="uTopTd">Логин</th><th class="uTopTd">Аватар/логотип</th><th class="uTopTd">Страна</th><th class="uTopTd">Город</th><th class="uTopTd">Дата входа</th><th class="uTopTd">cat-id</th></tr>
    <tr><td class="uTd">380939282099</td><td class="uTd">VIP-исполнители </td><td class="uTd"><a href="/index/8-2" target="_blank">keklol</a> <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-2-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a> </td><td class="uTd"><span class="user_avatar"><img alt="" border="0" src="/.s/a/27/919992219.png" width="30" align="absmiddle"></span></td><td class="uTd">Украина</td><td class="uTd">h</td><td class="uTd"><span title="12:30:19">Сегодня</span></td><td class="uTd">cat2,cat7</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="uTd">7426357678</td><td class="uTd">Исполнители </td><td class="uTd"> <a href="/index/8-15" target="_blank">lolkek</a> <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-15-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a> </td><td class="uTd"><span class="user_avatar"><img alt="" border="0" src="/.s/a/21/315356011.png" width="30" align="absmiddle"></span></td><td class="uTd">Российская Федерация</td><td class="uTd">lolkek</td><td class="uTd"><span title="23:03:22">05.09.2020</span></td><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td><td class="uTd">Исполнители </td><td class="uTd"> <a href="/index/8-22" target="_blank">Test1ispol</a> <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-22-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a> </td><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td><td class="uTd">Украина</td><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td><td class="uTd"><span title="18:53:29">Вчера</span></td><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td><td class="uTd">Заказчики </td><td class="uTd"> <a href="/index/8-21" target="_blank">Test1zakax</a> <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-21-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a> </td><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td><td class="uTd">Украина</td><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td><td class="uTd"><span title="23:42:50">Вчера</span></td><td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="uTd">+3806 * * * * * * 76</td><td class="uTd">Администраторы </td><td class="uTd"><a href="/index/8-1" target="_blank">Администратор</a> <span class="myWinSuccess">*</span> </td><td class="uTd"><span class="user_avatar"><img alt="" border="0" src="/avatar/00/00/00166064.jpg" width="30" align="absmiddle"></span></td><td class="uTd">Украина</td><td class="uTd">kkkkkkkk</td><td class="uTd"><span title="15:55:04">Сегодня</span></td><td class="uTd">cat8,cat9,cat11,cat12</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Как можно сделать проверку, если ни в одном td из одного tr НЕ найден "cat2", то удалить весь tr?
Я пробовал вот так:

```
$(".user-list tr td").filter(":not(:contains('cat2'))").each(function(){
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Но это, почему то, не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не работает (что есть "не работает"?), потому что во всех строках таблицы присутствуют клетки (хотя бы одна), в которых нет `'cat2'`.

```js
$(".user-list tr")
  .filter(function() { return !$(this).find("th").length; })
  .filter(":not(:contains('cat2'))")
  .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="uTable user-list">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="uTopTd">Телефон</th>
      <th class="uTopTd">Группа</th>
      <th class="uTopTd">Логин</th>
      <th class="uTopTd">Аватар/логотип</th>
      <th class="uTopTd">Страна</th>
      <th class="uTopTd">Город</th>
      <th class="uTopTd">Дата входа</th>
      <th class="uTopTd">cat-id</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uTd">380939282099</td>
      <td class="uTd">VIP-исполнители </td>
      <td class="uTd"><a href="/index/8-2" target="_blank">keklol</a>
        <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-2-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="uTd"><span class="user_avatar"><img alt="" border="0" src="/.s/a/27/919992219.png" width="30" align="absmiddle"></span></td>
      <td class="uTd">Украина</td>
      <td class="uTd">h</td>
      <td class="uTd"><span title="12:30:19">Сегодня</span></td>
      <td class="uTd">cat2,cat7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uTd">7426357678</td>
      <td class="uTd">Исполнители </td>
      <td class="uTd"> <a href="/index/8-15" target="_blank">lolkek</a>
        <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-15-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="uTd"><span class="user_avatar"><img alt="" border="0" src="/.s/a/21/315356011.png" width="30" align="absmiddle"></span></td>
      <td class="uTd">Российская Федерация</td>
      <td class="uTd">lolkek</td>
      <td class="uTd"><span title="23:03:22">05.09.2020</span></td>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="uTd">Исполнители </td>
      <td class="uTd"> <a href="/index/8-22" target="_blank">Test1ispol</a>
        <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-22-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="uTd">Украина</td>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="uTd"><span title="18:53:29">Вчера</span></td>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="uTd">Заказчики </td>
      <td class="uTd"> <a href="/index/8-21" target="_blank">Test1zakax</a>
        <a class="uPM" href="/index/14-21-0-1" title="Отправить Личное Сообщение"><img alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/.s/img/ma/e1.gif" width="12" height="13"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="uTd">Украина</td>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="uTd"><span title="23:42:50">Вчера</span></td>
      <td class="uTd">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uTd">+3806 * * * * * * 76</td>
      <td class="uTd">Администраторы </td>
      <td class="uTd"><a href="/index/8-1" target="_blank">Администратор</a> <span class="myWinSuccess">*</span> </td>
      <td class="uTd"><span class="user_avatar"><img alt="" border="0" src="/avatar/00/00/00166064.jpg" width="30" align="absmiddle"></span></td>
      <td class="uTd">Украина</td>
      <td class="uTd">kkkkkkkk</td>
      <td class="uTd"><span title="15:55:04">Сегодня</span></td>
      <td class="uTd">cat8,cat9,cat11,cat12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```